# Are there APIs to copy files from an iOS app's documents folder?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, appkit

If I connect my phone to my computer, I can select the phone in the finder (Catalina) or in iTunes (pre-Catalina).

Once selected, I can copy files from my Mac to the document folder of an app I have installed on my phone.

My question is whether or not there are public APIs that allow me to do this programmatically...?

Comment: It must be possible _somehow_ because iTunes / Finder can in fact do it, as you say yourself. And apps like iMazing can do it. Now, whether a normal human being can figure out how to do it, I've no idea. :)

Comment: Well, there are private APIs that allow Apple do to things regular developers cannot. iMazing may be using those or not. My (very) brief search didn't turn up anything obvious...I had some hope that libimobiledevice might support this, but didn't see anything obvious there either.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that Apple is very discrete as to how they allow people to access their private APIs. The closest thing I could find was this https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

This tutorial shows you how to integrate the Files app to your app, and from there, with enough tinkering, you should be able to figure out how to export them directly from your said app. Hope this helps.

Comment: I do not want to export files from an iOS app. I want to copy files from my desktop Mac to my iOS device. This is obviously possible because the finder and iTunes can do it, but as best I can determine the APIs which allow for this are private.